# Handle website URL in Cordova app

Tags: android, apache, cordova, url-scheme

I'm building an application for a website with Apache Cordova (eg. http://mywebsite.com ).
What I want to do is thant when someone point the browser to http://mywebsite.com/* he will be asked to continue opening the URL in the browser on to load the URL in the app I'm developing.
I mean an "Open with..." popup like YouTube app and URL do.

How can I do this? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Look up `app deep linking`

Answer (score 0):

You can use inAppBrowser cordova plugin, https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser

Installation

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
```

Sample code

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
    window.open = cordova.InAppBrowser.open;
}
```